# How would you refer to the parent of an appendix? i.e. a section linking to the parent(002) of a child(002a)?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the parent document, I have a section titled "Appendices" listing all of its children. But I have no idea what to name the callback to the parent in the child.

Is there an official-ish word for what I'm referring to?

Comment: Appendices almost never refer back to a so-called parent. Mainly because appendices are often called from *multiple* locations in the main document (at least in technical documents), so there is seldom a 1-1 relationship. The only thing that would normally have a 1-1 relationship between something in the main document and a note at its end would be an endnote. (But the same so-called parent of an endnote also has no name—other than, generically I suppose, the *referrer*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford That makes sense. Unfortunately in this case there is a somewhat 1:1 relationship. What I have is a main document (002) with multiple children (002a, 002b, 002c, etc).

Comment: I would say "intestines".

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re describing. The terms you use have established meanings that don’t seem to fit well in what you’ve written.

Answer (score -2):

> **Index**

According to Merriam-Webster:

"a list... arranged usually in alphabetical order of some specified datum"

source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/index